# 'array' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, stdvector

I've been looking for a resolution of this error for a while without success. There are a few answer to this topic and they did not help me at all. 
I am compiling on Linux Mint using codeblocks 12.11 a simple C++ program and I encountered
`error: 'array' is not a member of 'std'`

Some other answers suggested to check the Compiler Setting in: Settings -> Compiler -> Compiler settings -> Compiler Flags, and I thought the case: Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]. I still have the same error. Anybody can help?

Comment: WRT tags: `array` is not `vector`. Are you including `<array>`?

Comment: Did you forget to `#include <array>`?

Comment: Without showing any code, it's impossible to say what the problem is.

Comment: ... the code *and* the build log showing the compiler options applied and the actual error message.  You are asking us to "believe" a number of things when you could just provide evidence, and the same diagnostic information you have the benefit of.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just need to include header `<array>`

```
#include <array>
```

If the compiler does not support `std::array` then in this case it will issue an error that this header is not found.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the C++ 11 compiler flag:

`-std=c++0x` or
`-std=c++11`